# UIBarButtonItemStyleDone background image using the iOS 5 appearance API

Tags: ios5, appearance, uibarbuttonitemstyle

How can I provide a visually distinct bar button item background image for bar buttons with the UIBarButtonItemStyleDone style and the editing state of the Edit/Done button? None of the documented UIControlState values in the UIBarButtonItem appearance proxy's  setBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics: seem to do the trick.

Comment: Are you trying to customize the appearance of the buttons specifically or would you like a similar background for all UIBarButtons?

Comment: I second that question. Could only set one backgroundImage for [UIBarButtonItem appearance], but can't find how to set a different image for "Done" button. If I try to setBackgroundImage of the Done button's instance, it changes back to the default appearance. I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this was never answered but if you are still looking then simply create a property for a BarButtonItem in your .h, assign it in IB, then set the background property of that barButtonItem. Works fine for me and never "changes back to default appearance".

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.barButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YOURIMAGE"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found and posted a possible solution to this problem.
You can 'inject' custom styles using a UIBarButtonItem category:

> [Customizing UIBarButtonItem "Done" style and "Plain" style separately using UIAppearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12583574/customizing-uibarbuttonitem-done-style-and-plain-style-separately-using-uiap)