# How to set appearance for a UIButton without affecting UIBarButtonItems?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, appearance, uiappearance

Using the following code to customize regular UIButtons also affects UIBarButtonItems and clear buttons in text fields.

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundImage:greenButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I do **not** wish to customize the latter elements at all, only regular *round rect buttons*. I realize using appearanceWhenContainedIn: could be used to set a custom appearance for UIBarButtonItems and UITextField, but i wish for these buttons to remain standard. Subclassing is not an option here as it should not be required for such a simple task.

There is a similar question, but it does not address the issue. [Why does -[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundImage] affect the initial appearance of UIBarItem objects and how do you correct it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734419/why-does-uibutton-appearance-setbackgroundimage-affect-the-initial-appearan)

Comment: I was able to fix the UITextField problem by specifically setting those to a clear background image. Not a nice solution though.

Comment: How are you initializing your UIBarButtonItems?  Are you setting the "customView" property to be a UIButton object?  If you can provide sample code for how you create a UIBarButtonItem then I'm pretty sure I can help...I do lots of customisations with appearance proxies and bar buttons/UIButtons in my apps and haven't had these issues.

Answer (score 4):

One solution I've used before is to nil out the "backgroundImage" property for UIButtons contained inside of a UINavigationBar:

```
[[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class], nil] setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This should allow you to customize UIButtons in other cases, without touching the ones inside a UIBarButtonItem in the UINavigationBar.